# boundary conditions after change of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the nonlinear boundary value problem on $[0,1]$
$$ a_1 y'^2 - a_2y'^{5/2} - a_3y'' + y''y'^{1/2} = 0 \quad y(0) = 0, y(1) = 1 \tag 1 $$

If I change variables $s=y'^{1/2}$, then (1) becomes the system
$$ \begin{cases}
        a_1s^4 - a_2s^5 - 2a_3ss' + 2s^2s' &= 0\\
        s^2 &= y' 
   \end{cases}
$$
Question:  What is the boundary condition for $s(0)$ after the change of variables?

Comment: @martini that's a better job :)